# The 'this' keyword behaves differently in Nodejs and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this piece of code :

```
var obj1;
var obj2;

function x() {
    obj1 = this;
}

function y() {
    obj2 = this;
}

x();
y();

console.log(obj1 === obj2);
console.log(obj1 === this);
```

I ran this code in NodeJS using command line : node app.js and ran as a script in Chrome browser

The result : in NodeJS, the result was : true false
[NodeJS result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCWxi.png)

In Chrome browser, the result was : true true
[Browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvarb.png)

How can this happened ? can anyone explain what really going on under the hood ?

Comment: you might want to print out `this` to see what it actually is. In a browser it should be `window` by default, in node i am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 38):

In the browser, running in the global scope, `this` is always `window` in your example

```
var obj1;
var obj2;

function x() {
    obj1 = this; // window
}

function y() {
    obj2 = this; // window
}

x();
y();

console.log(obj1 === obj2);  // window === window = true
console.log(obj1 === this);  // window === window = true
```

This is not how it works in Node. In Node.js all modules (script files) are executed in their own [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) while browsers execute all script files directly within the global scope.

In other words, in just about any file running in Node, `this` will just be an empty object, as Node wraps the code in an anonymous function that is called immediately, and you'd access the global scope within that context with `GLOBAL` instead.

This is also mentioned in the [Globals documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects):

> Some of these objects aren't actually in the global scope but in the module scope - this will be noted.

However, when calling a function without a specific context in Node.js, it will normally be defaulted to the *global object* - The same [`GLOBAL`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) mentioned earlier, as it's execution context.

So outside the functions, `this` is an empty object, as the code is wrapped in a function by Node, to create it's own execution context for every module (script file), while inside the functions, because they are **called** with no specified execution context, `this` is the Node `GLOBAL` object

In Node.js you'd get

```
var obj1;
var obj2;

function x() {
    obj1 = this; // GLOBAL
}

function y() {
    obj2 = this; // GLOBAL
}

x();
y();

console.log(obj1 === obj2);  // GLOBAL === GLOBAL = true
console.log(obj1 === this);  // GLOBAL === {} = false
```

Where the last `this` is indeed an empty object, as explained above

---

For completeness, it's worth noting that in strict mode, you'd get the same result in a browser (`true, false`) as in Node, but that's because the variables are just the opposite of what they are in Node

```
"use strict"

var obj1;
var obj2;

function x() {
    obj1 = this; // undefined
}

function y() {
    obj2 = this; // undefined
}

x();
y();

console.log(obj1 === obj2);  // undefined === undefined = true
console.log(obj1 === this);  // undefined === window = false
```

This is because the value passed as `this` to a function in strict mode is not forced into being an object (a.k.a. "boxed").
For a normal function in non-strict mode, `this` is always an object, and it's always the global object if **called** with an `undefined` or `null` this-value, i.e. without a specific execution context.

Not only is [automatic boxing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript) a performance cost, but exposing the global object in browsers is a security hazard, because the global object provides access to functionality that *"secure"* JavaScript environments must restrict.

Thus for a strict mode function, the specified `this` is not boxed into an object, and if unspecified, `this` will be `undefined` inside functions, as shown above, but `this` will still be the window in the global scope.

The same thing happens in strict-mode in Node.js, where `this` inside the functions is no longer `GLOBAL` but `undefined`, and `this` outside the functions will still be the same empty object, and the end result will still be `true, false`, but the value of `this` will be different in strict-mode in Node.js as well.

Comment: Does anyone know *why* Node uses an empty object as the context when executing a module? (I can't imagine it is an attempt to protect the global, since the global is used as the context when a function is called.)

Comment: @joeytwiddle - I have no idea, I'm guessing every module ran is just put inside something like `(function() { code }());` and someone decided to make `this` an empty object, as `this` should always be defined, and they didn't want it to be the global object by default.

Comment: Perhaps it *is* an attempt to protect the global, but they still had to use the global as the context object when a function is called, because that is what the language specification demands.

Comment: You might want to mention how strict mode impacts this (pun intended:)

Answer (score 8):

Created a table to show the `this` value under different **scopes** and **modes**:

[image]

**Note:** In *Node environment*, the value of `this` **outside** the function means that `this` value is outside of
a function declaration but **within** the *anonymous* function wrapper created by node.js for achieving the *module* scope.

Answer (score 7):

Node explicitly sets `this` to the module exports [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/19f700859b55b96c7ed9bdeb68482c6a9d84e1b2/lib/module.js#L423):

```
const result = compiledWrapper.apply(this.exports, args);
```

What `apply` does is explicitly fixate the `this` value (and parameters) - in this case - it sets it to `this.exports`. For example you can do:

```
(function() { console.log(this.x); }).apply({x:3}); // alerts 3
```

Node override's the default behavior. It has to, however, call functions inside the object with `global` - as is mandated by the JS spec.

Comment: Note, this initially started as a comment on adeneo's answer - I decided since it stands for itself I'd post it as a separate answer and upvote his. See his answer for more _reasoning_ rather than "here's the code that makes it happen".

Answer (score 5):

The difference is pretty simple

In the node environment :

**this** refers to `module.exports` or `exports` for short.
but inside a function **this** is refering to the entire **Node.js** package.

you can see it if you log to the console the following :

```
function test(){
    console.log('this inside a function = ',this);
}

console.log('this outside a function = ',this);
test();
```

Whereas in the browser environment **this inside a function or outside a function** is referring to the  **window object** unless you are using the **new** keyword which is another story.

Execute the previous example in both Node.js and browser environments and you will understand.

Comment: In strict mode - this would be undefined inside the function

Answer (score 3):

In the Browser-Context the last this points to the Windowobject, which does exist in Node-Context. Therefore the last this is an empty object. The occurrences of this in the functions however point to some global object in the Node-Context.

Answer (score 2):

I have no Node.js server in a hand right now, but I think you can yourself research this question, and give answer for us :D see code below

Try to run:

`console.log(this.constructor.name+" "+obj1.constructor.name+" "+obj2.constructor.name);`

And also you can debug "Parent Class" name in a function:

```
function x() {
    console.log("x this: "+this.constructor.name);
    obj1 = this;
}

function y() {
    console.log("y this: "+this.constructor.name);
    obj2 = this;
}
```

And for view Object methods / properties you can use something like this:

```
for (a in obj2) {
    console.log("obj2." + a + " = " + obj2[a]);
}
```