# NodeJS this reference

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code

```
this.userInfo = 'bla';

    request({
        url: 'https://api.api.ai/v1/entities?v=20150910',
        headers : {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.APIAI_ACCESS_TOKEN
        },
        method: 'GET'
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
        }
        console.log(this.userInfo);
    }.bind(this));
```

When I try to print the `this.userInfo` variable I get `undefined` but I  did the `bind()` on `this`. Could someone explain me what's going on ?

Comment: seems it should work fine, you must be re-assigning `userInfo`

Comment: Alessandro, scope of this is lost in function in which you have used this.userInfo

Answer (score 4):

In your code scope of `this` is override by other functions so the value which you have set is not available.
When you call bind with `this` which is available out side function then it have same value as you have set, see below corrected code.

```
let self= this;
    self.userInfo = 'bla'; 
        request({
            url: 'https://api.api.ai/v1/entities?v=20150910',
            headers : {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.APIAI_ACCESS_TOKEN
            },
            method: 'GET'
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
            } else if (response.body.error) {
                console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
            }
    //scope of 'this' in callback function are removed, so have set value to self variable 
            console.log(self.userInfo);
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: I see :). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend checking out the [MDN article on the `this` keyword in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), to me it looks like you're misunderstanding the purpose of the `this` keyword in JavaScript.

In Node.js it's slightly different too, in the browser in the global scope, `this` is always `window`.

In Node.js all modules are executed in their own closure, whereas by default browsers run the global scope.

TL;DR as far as I know you can't write code like this in JS. [Check out this StackOverflow answer for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838985/2344348).

Instead of using `this` you may want to setup a variable within that module, and store `userInfo` into that.