# Javascript this and naming vs. not naming variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, this

```
"use script";

var user = {
    name: "John Doe",
    career: "Civil Engineer",
    socialMedia: {
        fb: "www.facebook.com/johndoe",
        twitter: "www.twitter.com/johndoe"
    },
    about: function() {
        console.log("My name is " + this.name + " and I am a " + this.career);
    }
}

var name = "Jen";
var career = "Dentist";

user.about();

var newAction = user.about;

newAction(); // My name is undefined and I am a undefined
```

Why is `newAction()` returning undefined name and career but when I remove the `var` from:

```
var name = "Jen";
var career = "Dentist";
```

to

name = "Jen";
career = "Dentist";

then I execute `newAction()` again and get:

`newAction() // My name is Jen and I am a Dentist`

Comment: what should *use script* do??

Comment: How does one define, declare, etc a variable without a name? No identifier? If you exclude `var` then it will be a global and all of it's faults along with it will cause you unnecessary grief.

Answer (score 1):

nodejs code does not run in global scope, but in some kind of function instance:

```
//(function(module){
  var some=5;
 console.log(global.some);//undefined
//})(..)
```

So if you declare a variable, it is not part of *global* which *this* refers to, its just in the invisible function scope ( thats a difference to browsers where var in the highest scope are part of window).

If you leave away the declaration (not good, not in strict mode), it gets scoped globally, and therefore becomes part of *global* aka *this* in functions. So may do:

```
global.name="John";
newAction();//this===global
```

[The 'this' keyword behaves differently in Nodejs and browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838659/the-this-keyword-behaves-differently-in-nodejs-and-browser)